# Why adding a PPA doesn't ask (y/n)?

Tags: apt, ppa

On ubuntu and few other distros I've tried, when the user is prompted with a yes or no question, 99% of the time it prompts the user to input `y` or `n` depending on the choice. But the only exception to this --that I have seen so far-- is when adding a ppa using the `add-apt-repository` command. It asks you to hit ENTER to continue, or ctrl-c to cancel. Is there a specific reason behind this or is it just the way it was designed?

Comment: Sounds like a case for [100 papercuts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PaperCut). But I'm not sure if this is still in action...

Answer (score -1):

You can read script by command : `cat /usr/bin/add-apt-repository`. In which following lines are related to this:

```py
# display more information about the shortcut / ppa info
    if not options.assume_yes and shortcut.should_confirm():
        try:
            info = shortcut.info()
        except ShortcutException as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(1)

        print(" %s" % (info["description"] or ""))
        print(_(" More info: %s") % str(info["web_link"]))
        if (sys.stdin.isatty() and
            not "FORCE_ADD_APT_REPOSITORY" in os.environ):
            if options.remove:
                print(_("Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel removing it"))
            else:
                print(_("Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it"))
            sys.stdin.readline()
```

Hence it asks `Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it` which is designed and if you want to get rid of this then use : `-y` or `--yes` to **Assume yes to all queries**.

Comment: That's the how, but not the why, which is what this question is asking.

Comment: This comes from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/software-properties-common).